# Why is bash not recognizing my newline character?

Tags: bash-scripting, vi

I am trying to get a script to reverse the order of entrees ( yes I know "tac" command already does this) my script is as follows, The print F line that prints the array value and then is followed by a new line, will not print my newline, and it is really annoying.

I tried separating it out and having printf "\n" on the line immediately following the line to print the array index value, but that doesn't seem to be working either.

```
#!/bin/bash

a=()
while read line; do
    a+="$line"
done

for ((i = 0 ; i <= ${#a[@]} ; i++)); do
    printf "${a[$i]}\n"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not your `printf` statement, but your assignment while reading - you are mixing the syntax of *appending to array* with *assigning the value of an element*. To append to array, you need to use `a+=("$line")` instead. If you wanted to use the syntax without parenthesis, you'd need to specify the index of element you want to change, for example `a[5]="$line"`.

You can find more examples about arrays for example in [this Stackovewflow documentation link (check the part "Array modification")](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/bash/471/arrays#t=201704211236290541116).

Also note that your script is not printing the lines in reverse order. To do this, you need to reverse the `for` cycle to iterate from the end of the array to the beginning.